# Python for loop with two related variables

Tags: python, list

I have a list of names:

```
names = ['ALICE', 'BOB', 'ME']
```

Take `'A'` as 1, `'B'` as 2, `'C'` as 3... The sum of 'ALICE' can be calculated with:

```
sum([ord(i) - ord('A') + 1 for i in 'ALICE'])  // ALICE: 30, BOB: 19, ME: 18
```

Now, I want to calculate all the sum in names multiplied with index in the `names`, e.g., 30 * 1 + 19 * 2 + 18 * 3 = 122.

It's easy to do this like:

```
s = 0
for i in range(len(names)):
    s += sum(([ord(j) - ord('A') + 1) * (i + 1) for j in names[i]])
print s
```

But I want to learn to do this in list generator style (in one line perhaps). How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> names = ['ALICE', 'BOB', 'ME']
>>> sum(i * sum(ord(ch) - ord('A') + 1 for ch in name) for i, name in enumerate(names, 1))
122
```

[`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) accepts any iterable, so you can pass generator expression instead of list comprehension.

---

```
>>> enumerate('ALICE')
<enumerate object at 0x7f8f7b8c42d0>
>>> list(enumerate('ALICE'))
[(0, 'A'), (1, 'L'), (2, 'I'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'E')]
>>> list(enumerate('ALICE', 1))
[(1, 'A'), (2, 'L'), (3, 'I'), (4, 'C'), (5, 'E')]
```